# Intents and their parameters

Tags: android, android-intent, parameters

It seems like from the various tutorials ive seen people would jump from one activity to another by calling intents from the activity they are working on.
ex:intent(this, anotheractivity.class)

sometimes I see people just using the class they are going to as the parameter

ex: intent (android.content.blahblahblah)

whats the difference in functionality? 
is the second made for default classes?

help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are two "types" of Intents. One is called and explicit Intent in which you tell Android the specific class you are trying to reach (i.e. MyClass.class). The other case uses Android's  filtering system to give you the best "match" for the Class you are targeting. When you call `new Intent(String action)` you are specifying an action to match with some `IntentFilter`. If your app shares the `IntentFilter` with some other app, then a dialog will pop up so the user can select which app he/she wants to use.